# Validating Password Loop using control structures

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program where a string (password) is read from the terminal.
the password has to be atleast 8 char long, must have an upper and lower case letter, a digit and no space.

here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
string pw;  
char i; 
bool hasLow=0, hasUpp=0, hasdigit=0, hasspace=0, status=0;
 
do {
  
cout<<"What will be your  password?"<<endl; 
getline (cin,pw);
  for (int i = 0; i < pw.length(); i++) {
  if (isupper(pw[i]))  hasUpp =1; 
  if (islower (pw[i]))  hasLow=1; 
  if (isdigit(pw[i])) hasdigit=1; 
  if (!(isspace (pw[i])))  hasspace=1;    }
  
  cout<<"password is invalid. Please try again."<<endl; 
  }

while ( (hasUpp) && (hasLow) && (hasdigit) && (hasspace) && (pw.length() >= 8));
{cout<<"Password is valid";} }
```

I can't get the do while loop to work (has to be do while) and the password is accepted even if there is a space

Comment: Please do not spam the tags, this question has nothing to do with `c`

Comment: Additionally, the question has nothing to do with C++11, C++14 and C++17. I removed those tags also.

Comment: A couple of obvious issues: you don't reset hasUpp etc when you enter a new password and the loop keeps going while the password is valid. Also - fix the formatting. You'd be surprised how often that helps find issues

Comment: you print the error message before you check that all the conditions have been mer

Comment: sorry abt the tag spam, just started using this site so wasn't sure how to get an answer quickly but regardless , really sorry abt that!

Comment: PSA: `true` and `false` exist.

Comment: You also don't need (paranoia) brackets around your logical tests. `while (hasUpp && hasLow && ...)` is fine. Note that you don't really care about which test failed, which means you can consolidate those and be more like `fail ||= isupper(...)` to accumulate failures, then `while (fail)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not resetting your `bool`s on each loop iteration. Your loop condition is wrong. And your `invalid` message is in the wrong place.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
    string pw;  
    char ch; 
    bool hasLow, hasUpp, hasdigit, hasspace;
 
    do {
        cout << "What will be your password?" << endl; 
        getline (cin, pw);

        hasLow = hasUpp = hasdigit = hasspace = false;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < pw.length(); ++i) {
            ch = pw[i];
            if (isupper(ch))      hasUpp = true; 
            else if (islower(ch)) hasLow = true; 
            else if (isdigit(ch)) hasdigit = true; 
            else if (isspace(ch)) hasspace = true;
        }
  
        if ((hasUpp) && (hasLow) && (hasdigit) && (!hasspace) && (pw.length() >= 8))
            break;

        cout << "password is invalid. Please try again." << endl;
    }
    while (true);

    cout << "Password is valid";
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/RsaAgy)

Comment: thanks a lot!!! that makes so much sense